# How do I calculate the average of different ranges in the same column in Excel preferably using command button?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using Excel 2013. There are around fifty worksheets and I've to calculate hundreds of averages in a worksheet. The data is spread like C3:C10, C12:C16, C18:C35, etc. and I want to calculate the average at the end of each of these ranges like C11, C17, C36, etc. The range always lie within the same column and each range is separated by two blank cells but the range is not fixed.

I tried recording a macro.

```
Sub Averaging() 
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-12]C:R[-1]C)"
End Sub
```

But I don't know how to make R[-12]C part dynamic. I was thinking of creating a command button which after selecting the cell, for example the range is C3:C10 and I select cell C11, and upon pressing the command button it will automatically pick the range and calculate the average. Is it possible?

Any help will be appreciated. VBA, formulas anything.

Comment: If the data is always in column C, one question is will the data always start in C1?  If C1 is a header row with text, will the Data always start in C2?  or can the first number in column C appear at any point?  Also will there only be numbers and empty cells in column C, or will their be text as well?

Comment: Also, do you want a formula dumped into the cell that calculates the average of the range, or do you want to calculate the range within VBA and dump the average value instead.  both methods work

Comment: Will your range of number that needs to be averaged ever wind up being a single number or rather a range 1 row long?

Comment: @ForwardEd The data is not always in column C. Mostly in column M and column AA. Data always start with second row. First row has header. Only numbers in these columns and no texts.

Any method will do.

I don't understand. What do you mean by 1 row long?

Comment: I was asking if with your random range lengths of sometimes 4, 10, 12, 3, 16 number long, if you ever have to deal with the case of a single number... and now I see your comment on this down below.

Comment: @ForwardEd No, it is always more than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the first cell with data in column **C** and run this macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set r1 = ActiveCell
    Do
        Set r2 = r1.End(xlDown)
        If r2.Row = Rows.Count Then Exit Sub
        r2.Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Range(r1, r2).Address(0, 0) & ")"
        Set r1 = r2.Offset(3, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Comment: What if the data is in column M and AA? It is working for column C. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What happens if c2 is a number and C3 and C4 are blank.  ie he is trying to average a single number as that is how the list of random numbers got spit out?

Comment: There is no such case of averaging a single. It is always two or more.
@ForwardEd

Comment: I believe gary's macro will work in any column that is selected.  You just need to select the first number in the column

Comment: Oh yes! It is working. Thank you so much. Really appreciate it.
@gary'sstudent

Comment: Raking up an old problem.

Answer (score 1):

you could use

```
Sub WriteAverage(columnRng As Range)
Dim iArea As Long

With columnRng.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Areas
    For iArea = 1 To .Count
        With .Item(iArea).Cells
            .Offset(.Rows.Count).Resize(1).FormulaR1C1 = "=average(R" & .Cells(1, 1).Row & "C:R[-1]C)"
        End With
    Next iArea
End With

End Sub
```

to be called like follows

```
Call WriteAverage(Columns("C"))
```